# Android: Playing one media file at one time from listview

Tags: android, listview, media

i have create one listview which contain 4 media file to play.If i am select 1st song to play,it is playing but if i select socond song on listview to play then both are playing so i want that if second will be select to play then first need to be stop and only second song  need to be play. Kindly help me solve such issue...Thank in advance.
Below is my code.
Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private ArrayList<String> audioList;
private File file;
private ListView lvAudio;
private Context context;
private Adapter Adaptr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    audioList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String root_sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    file = new File( root_sd + "/EmoticApp/AudioFile/" ) ;
    File list[] = file.listFiles();

    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        audioList.add( list[i].getName() );
    }

    getid();
    setListner();

    Adaptr = new Adapter(MainActivity.this,audioList);
    lvAudio.setAdapter(Adaptr);
}

private void setListner() {

    lvAudio.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void getid() {

    lvAudio =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvAudio);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


}
```

}

Adapter code:

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {


ArrayList<String> audioList;
Context context;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public boolean flag =false;

public Adapter(MainActivity mainActivity, ArrayList<String> audioList) {

    this.context = mainActivity;
    this.audioList = audioList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return audioList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class Holder {
    private ImageView imgIcon, imgPlay, imgPause, imgStop;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private SeekBar seekbar;
    private TextView tvTotalTime,duration;
    private double timeElapsed = 0, finalTime = 0;
    private int forwardTime = 2000, backwardTime = 2000;
    private Handler durationHandler = new Handler();

    //handler to change seekBarTime
    private Runnable updateSeekBarTime = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //get current position
            timeElapsed = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            //set seekbar progress
            seekbar.setProgress((int) timeElapsed);

            tvTotalTime.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) finalTime), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) finalTime)));

            //set time remaing
            double timeRemaining = finalTime - timeElapsed;
            duration.setText(String.format("%d min, %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds((long) timeRemaining) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes((long) timeRemaining))));

            //repeat yourself that again in 100 miliseconds
            durationHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View myView = convertView;
    final Holder holder;

    if (myView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_adapter, null);

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imgPlay = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);
        holder.imgPause = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imgPause);
        holder.imgStop = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imgStop);
        holder.seekbar =(SeekBar)myView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        holder.tvTotalTime =(TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.tvTotalTime);
        holder.duration =(TextView)myView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        holder.seekbar.setClickable(true);

        holder.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                if (fromUser) {
                    holder.mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        String fileName = audioList.get(position);
        String path="/EmoticApp/AudioFile/";
        Log.e("Checking File:", "Checking=======:" + fileName);

        flag =true;

        holder.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+path + fileName));

        holder.imgPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (flag == true) {

                    holder.mediaPlayer.start();
                    if (holder.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        holder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.timeElapsed = holder.mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                        holder.seekbar.setProgress((int) holder.timeElapsed);
                        holder.durationHandler.postDelayed(holder.updateSeekBarTime, 100);
                        holder.finalTime = holder.mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                        holder.seekbar.setMax((int) holder.finalTime);

                        Toast.makeText(context,"Playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.imgPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                holder.mediaPlayer.pause();
                holder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        holder.mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                holder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                holder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        myView.setTag(holder);

        return myView;
    }

    return myView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use this lines of code:

```
 MediaPlayer        mp = new MediaPlayer();

    playMySong(String songPath)
    {
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource(songPath);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't create MediaPlayer instance for individual row of list. Let it be property of Adapter because this will help us to detect whether this media player is playing some song currently or not

So do this

```
    public class MyAdapter{
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();// I am ignoring exact constructor

        //now in your getView method do like this

    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       //.............prev code
        holder.imgPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.pause();
                        holder.imgPause.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        holder.imgPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{
                           mp.reset();
                           mp.setDataSource(Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+path + fileName));
                           mp.prepare();
                           mp.start();
                         //set other things   
                    }
            }
        });
        //......some code below
      }
}
```

Hope this will help you !!!!

Comment: Hi.
Thanks you so much for help me. I tried as you mention above code to resolve my issue but if i press second button on list to play the song then fist and second both are paused and if i agin press socond button to play the song then first and second, both song are playing and seekbar showing its remaining duration. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

As you progress in your application, you will find out that there would be other activities or fragment which may try to play some music and you will fall in same circumstances, Otherwise you might think that you just want to stop music as you come out of this list activity.

instead of going though the hustle of managing the instance of `MediaPlayer` make just make it once in the Application inside a class which will handle your business for playing the music, in your current case what is happening is the `MediaPlayer` API of android keep getting the request for playing music and by no means that these API can't handle multiple request so they will keep on playing as you command them,

in your custom class you gotta check if your `MediaPlayer` instance is still playing or not like this...

```
player.isPlaying()
```

if it is playing than stop it, like this

```
player.stop()
```

and give it some new data what you want it to play.